# Image highlighting using transparency (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to overlay a semi-transparent solid color image over a ROI in another image.

This code overlays one image on the other one:

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png')); % Sample
imshow(I) 

% Making an image which is all one colour:
c = {0.00  0.75  0.75}; % color code (e.g. sky blue)
overlay = cat(3, c{1}*ones(size(I)), c{2}*ones(size(I)), c{3}*ones(size(I)));

hold on 
h = imshow(overlay); 
hold off 

set(h, 'AlphaData', I)
```

These were the two images:

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]

However, we only want to highlight a specific region of the image (not the entire image). How can we do this?

For instance, if we select a rectangular ROI using imrect(...):

```
hh = imrect();
roi = round(wait(hh));
x1 = roi(1);
x2 = x1 + roi(3);
y1 = roi(2);
y2 = y1 + roi(4);
```

Is there any way to overlay the second image only over these chosen pixels (y1:y2, x1:x2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about painting the selected pixels?

```
II=repmat(I,1,1,3);
II(y1:y2,x1:x2,1)=II(y1:y2,x1:x2,1)+c{1}*256;
II(y1:y2,x1:x2,2)=II(y1:y2,x1:x2,1)+c{2}*256;
II(y1:y2,x1:x2,3)=II(y1:y2,x1:x2,1)+c{3}*256;
figure;imshow(II)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But using this approach (i.e. if you zero them out or change them to ones), you are still affecting the brightness of unchosen pixels, which is not what we want ideally.

Answer (score 0):

I make the following code, I hope you find it useful.

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png')); % Sample
imshow(I)

% Get the index of cut image
[Y, X] = ginput(2);

% Sort values to easily work with them
Y = sort(Y);
X = sort(X);

% The size of new image
M = round((X(2)-X(1)) +1);
N = round((Y(2)-Y(1)) +1);

% Cut the original image
I2 = I(round(X(1):X(2)), round(Y(1):Y(2)));

% The new image
R = zeros(M, N ,3);

% Set the values of color you want
R(:,:,3) = 0.75;
R(:,:,2) = 0.75;

% Normalize the image to [0 255] uint8
R = im2uint8(R);

% Add the original image
R(:,:,1) = I2;

imshow(R)
```